# Multi Effect with Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, effect

With Firemonkey (Berlin Update 2) does it's possible to have on a TButton a TShadowEffect and a TGlowEffect who work together ?

To get the Shadow Effect I need to disabled the Glow Effect.

Answer (score 8):

Make a compound component: Put your TButton inside a TRectangle (shape);  Attach the TShadowEffect to the TButton and the TGlowEffect to the outer TRectangle container.

```
unit FMX_TwoEffects;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Effects,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Objects;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    ShadowEffect1: TShadowEffect;
    GlowEffect1: TGlowEffect;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

(FMX file)

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 146
  ClientWidth = 243
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Rectangle1: TRectangle
    Fill.Kind = None
    Position.X = 20.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 20.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 113.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 37.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Stroke.Kind = None
    object Button1: TButton
      Align = Client
      Size.Width = 113.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 37.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'Button1'
      object ShadowEffect1: TShadowEffect
        Distance = 5.000000000000000000
        Direction = 45.000000000000000000
        Softness = 0.300000011920929000
        Opacity = 0.600000023841857900
        ShadowColor = claBlack
      end
    end
    object GlowEffect1: TGlowEffect
      Softness = 0.400000005960464400
      GlowColor = claGold
      Opacity = 0.899999976158142100
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's what I do, but it is not very practical. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: You can also use TLayout, as described in documentation: [http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_FireMonkey_Image_Effects]

Comment: Fixed link of zdzichs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_FireMonkey_Image_Effects#Applying_Multiple_Effects_to_a_Picture